# Making rank() ignore null cases

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out a way to make the `rank()` window function "skip" in its counting some rows with null values in a specific column. Pretty much, what I want is to count how many *paid* transactions there are, for each client, before each transaction/row.

I tried using `case when` inside the `rank()` and I got something similar to the results I expect, but still not quite what I need.

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                  What I need                          |
+-------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
| CLIENT      | CODE | PAYMENT  | PAID_PURCHASES_SO_FAR |
| A           | 341  | 17/09/21 | 0                     |
| A           | 342  | 18/09/21 | 1                     |
| A           | 343  | (null)   | 2                     |
| A           | 344  | 18/09/21 | 2                     |
| A           | 345  | 19/09/21 | 3                     |
| A           | 346  | 19/09/21 | 4                     |
| A           | 347  | (null)   | 5                     |
| A           | 348  | 24/09/21 | 5                     |
| B           | 855  | (null)   | 0                     |
| B           | 856  | 20/09/21 | 0                     |
| B           | 857  | (null)   | 1                     |
+-------------+------+----------+-----------------------+


-+------------------------------------------------------+
 |                  What I got                          |
-+------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
 | CLIENT     | CODE | PAYMENT  | PAID_PURCHASES_SO_FAR |
 | A          | 341  | 17/09/21 | 0                     |
 | A          | 342  | 18/09/22 | 1                     |
 | A          | 343  | (null)   | (null)                |
 | A          | 344  | 18/09/22 | 2                     |
 | A          | 345  | 19/09/22 | 3                     |
 | A          | 346  | 19/09/21 | 4                     |
 | A          | 347  | (null)   | (null)                |
 | A          | 348  | 24/09/21 | 5                     |
 | B          | 855  | (null)   | (null)                |
 | B          | 856  | 20/09/21 | 0                     |
 | B          | 857  | (null)   | (null)                |
-+------------+------+----------+-----------------------+
```

In a single image: [comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aghaV.png)

And here my code:

```
SELECT 
  CLIENT
, CODE
, PAYMENT
, CASE WHEN PAYMENT IS NOT NULL THEN DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY CLIENT, (CASE WHEN PAYMENT IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ORDER BY CODE) - 1 END NUMBER_OF_PURCHASES_SO_FAR 
FROM FOO.BAR
```

Note: The `CODE` column may be used as time reference. E.g. `code = 750` came before `code = 751`, and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: whats your rank function be like ?? I mean PAID_PURCHASES_SO_FAR will be logically what

Comment: you should ignore -1 in your case!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation combined with a window frame, as in:

```
select *, coalesce(sum(case when payment is null then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(partition by client order by code 
                 rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding), 0)
  as ppsf
from t
order by client, code
```

Result:

```
 client  code  payment   ppsf 
 ------- ----- --------- ---- 
 A       341   17/09/21  0    
 A       342   18/09/21  1    
 A       343   null      2    
 A       344   18/09/21  2    
 A       345   19/09/21  3    
 A       346   19/09/21  4    
 A       347   null      5    
 A       348   24/09/21  5    
 B       855   null      0    
 B       856   20/09/21  0    
 B       857   null      1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g84T2_y5).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
That's exactly what I need. Also, your code is crystal clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

This is it:

```
SELECT 
  "CLIENT"
, "CODE"
, "PAYMENT"
, rank() over(partition by "CLIENT" 
              order by COALESCE("PAYMENT",'01/01/70') )
FROM Table1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f941a/14

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but that doesn't return what it's expected.